# RIP Jeremy Bulloch. Original trilogy Boba Fett actor

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

Jeremy Bulloch, the actor who portrayed Boba Fett in the original trilogy *Star Wars* movies, has died at the age of 75.

In addition to his iconic role as the bounty hunter Fett, he also starred in several episodes of *Doctor Who* and eagle-eyed viewers will have spotted him as Captain Colton in *Star Wars: Revenge of the Sith* (2005).

[image]

Answer (score 10):

He also killed the original Sontaran, Linx from "The Time Warrior."

Answer (score 7):

R.I.P.

FWIW, he also played [Lt. Sheckil](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Sheckil) — the Imperial creep who was detaining Leia, Chewbacca and no-legs C3P0 — in *The Empire Strikes Back* (1980). Two roles in one scene.

[image]